# Animation to Home Page Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an opening animation on a personal project and I'm trying to then transition the animation to what would be my home page. The animation is done in CSS but would like to do it in JavaScript.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }
  
  .typing-demo {
    width: 22ch;
    animation: typing 2s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 3px solid;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  
  @keyframes typing {
    from {
      width: 0
    }
  }
      
  @keyframes blink {
    50% {
      border-color: transparent
    }
  }
```

This is the code for the animation

Comment: That's not a question, it's a ToDo item.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let typingDemo = document.querySelectorAll(".typing-demo");
    
typingDemo.style.animation = "typing 2s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate";
```

Comment: Good answers provide some explanation, not just code.